# Getting this following error when I'm trying to train the RNN Model

Tags: python, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

```
`import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
import random

# Load the poetry corpus
with open("./poems.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read().lower()

# Define emotions and corresponding keywords
emotions = {
    "love": ["love", "heart", "passion", "devotion"],
    "sadness": ["sadness", "tears", "pain", "sorrow"],
    "joy": ["joy", "happiness", "ecstasy", "bliss"]
}
SEQ_LENGTH = 40
STEP_SIZE = 3

# Preprocess the text
words = sorted(list(set(text.split())))
word_indices = dict((w, i) for i, w in enumerate(words))
indices_word = dict((i, w) for i, w in enumerate(words))

# Define the model architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(SEQ_LENGTH, len(words))))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(len(words), activation="softmax"))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")

# Train the model
for epoch in range(50):
    for i in range(0, len(text) - SEQ_LENGTH, STEP_SIZE):
        input_sequence = text[i:i + SEQ_LENGTH]
        output_sequence = text[i + SEQ_LENGTH]
        X = np.zeros((1, SEQ_LENGTH, len(words)), dtype=bool)
        for t, word in enumerate(input_sequence):
            X[0, t, word_indices[word]] = 1
        y = np.zeros((1, len(words)), dtype=bool)
        y[0, word_indices[output_sequence]] = 1
        model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, epochs=1)

# Define the emotion and generate poem
emotion = "sadness"
keywords = emotions[emotion]
seed_text = random.choice(keywords)
generated_text = seed_text

for i in range(20):
    x_pred = np.zeros((1, SEQ_LENGTH, len(words)))
    for t, word in enumerate(generated_text):
        x_pred[0, t, word_indices[word]] = 1.
    preds = model.predict(x_pred, verbose=0)[0]
    next_index = np.argmax(preds)
    next_word = indices_word[next_index]
    generated_text += " " + next_word

# Print the generated poem
print(generated_text)
```

`

This is the code which I'm using for generate the poem based on the emotion but when I'm trying to train the model I'm getting this following error.

> X[0, t, word_indices[word]] = 1
> KeyError: ' '

Can anyone help me with this issue?

I was trying to the train RNN model for generate the poem based on the emotion.